# how to make an array of D-dimensional coordinates from D arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

In numpy, I have D arrays each of length n, and I would like to produce a length n array of D-dimensional coordinates from those arrays. Each array, then, provides the values for one axis of the coordinates.

For example, in 2 dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5)
y = x + 4

#from which I would like to make this nd.array:
[[0, 4],
 [1, 5],
 [2, 6],
 [3, 7],
 [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack((x, y))
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

`column_stack` takes a sequence of arrays, so if you have `D` arrays you want to stack, you can call `column_stack` with D directly.